# Efficient way for mapping array values

Tags: python, numpy, mapping

I have `numpy` array, and I do want to map the ranges of the array values into specific values:

```py
import numpy as np

array = [
[328, 124, 146, 117, 147, 109, 139, 100, 140, 98, 128, 101, 121, 95, 111, 89, 114, 82, 106, 77, 97, 71, 273], 
[132, 121, 121, 117, 114, 110, 99, 163, 89, 81, 83, 81, 91, 91, 89, 144, 89, 81, 81, 75, 69, 68, 68], 
[164, 114, 117, 110, 105, 105, 97, 91, 142, 80, 131, 77, 122, 81, 108, 74, 77, 75, 69, 71, 68, 63, 87], 
[121, 116, 110, 103, 104, 99, 90, 84, 77, 137, 77, 125, 99, 128, 79, 73, 69, 71, 68, 70, 60, 53, 64], 
[151, 100, 103, 99, 379, 88, 264, 78, 135, 77, 121, 97, 113, 75, 100, 62, 232, 65, 350, 54, 56, 50, 75], 
[101, 93, 121, 90, 84, 92, 86, 78, 74, 113, 66, 115, 72, 100, 63, 67, 60, 57, 57, 47, 47, 44, 43], 
[146, 89, 116, 86, 87, 85, 79, 73, 101, 59, 98, 63, 107, 64, 62, 56, 56, 52, 48, 50, 46, 38, 68], 
[89, 113, 108, 83, 82, 78, 74, 125, 69, 67, 57, 65, 67, 56, 58, 105, 49, 52, 69, 59, 63, 34, 43], 
[127, 87, 78, 79, 105, 74, 163, 64, 61, 61, 56, 235, 61, 48, 51, 43, 134, 40, 63, 28, 31, 26, 55], 
[76, 79, 75, 70, 72, 69, 62, 58, 53, 52, 49, 50, 53, 43, 39, 37, 41, 36, 31, 29, 26, 18, 17], 
[274, 73, 96, 71, 92, 64, 87, 57, 82, 53, 81, 30, 73, 41, 66, 37, 52, 31, 49, 22, 50, 15, 211]]

array = np.array(array)

def mapVal(val, table = [140, 195, 250, 350, 450]):
    """
    Function: mapVal, to quantify depth values manually.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: val, nd-array.
    @param: table, list, mapping table.

    ---
    @return: None.
    """
    
    val[val <= table[0]]  = 0
    val[val >  table[0] & val <=  table[1]]  = 1
    val[val >  table[1] & val <=  table[2]]  = 2
    val[val >  table[2] & val <=  table[3]]  = 3
    val[val >  table[3] & val <=  table[4]]  = 4
    val[val >  table[4]]  = 5
```

But I'm getting this Error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I'm awar that I can use inefficient loops, but I do like to ask if there is a better solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you calling mapVal?

Comment: @EmiOB like this: `mapVal(array)`

Comment: You need to add parenthesis - e.g. `val[(val > table[0]) & (val <= table[1])]`, since the `&` is a bitwise operation and takes priority by default. This should address your `ValueError`

Comment: @rcshon thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: Does this fully answer your question? or are you still in search for a "more efficient" way?

Comment: @rcshon actually it solves my problem, but I don't mind a more efficient way if possible.

Comment: You method is already decent. Perhaps use a for-loop for conciseness. If you really must find a more efficient way, you can use `np.digitize(array, table)` in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, first solve your `ValueError` by using parenthesis around your conditional checks to avoid having the bit-wise and operator `&` be evaluated first, which is the default behaviour.

For example:

`val[(val > table[0]) & (val <= table[1])]`

Next, for your search for a more efficient method, you can use the built-in `np.digitize` function to help you do what you're doing:

`np.digitize(array, table)`

Comment: `np.digitize(array, table)` doesn't yield the same output of my manual function `mapVal`.

Comment: they should be the same. perhaps ensure that you are passing a new instance of the array with the original values for verification since your function modifies the input array.

Comment: For `np.digitize` to work correctly, the table should contain all the values and not just some of them. Otherwise some values are not replaced. Thus, the map should be corrected first. On solution is to use `np.searchsorted` to generate it. Boundaries also still need to be checked. This approach should be pretty fast.

Comment: You are right. that's oversight on my part

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler and much faster way to do what you want:

```py
table = np.array([140, 195, 250, 350, 450])
result = np.searchsorted(table, array)
```

This assume that the table is *sorted* though which is the case here. If it is not, then you can use `np.argsort` to reorder the table and `np.digitize` to remap the values.

Comment: thanks for your kind suggestion, I have compared the output of of my manual function `mapVal`, and it looks different from the output of your solution, the objective of `mapVal` function is to generate a discrete output with values `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` that corresponds to pre-defined ranges.

Comment: This is surprising. I checked the results and it was fine on my machine with your example. Note that your function *mutate* the input array so you certainly need to reload the values between the use of your function and the proposed code. Alternatively, you can `.copy()` the input array so to be safe.

Comment: you are right, thanks for your kind explanation